Using GLMs or GLMMs for diversity metrics
I would appreciate some help in a question regarding statistical analysis. I'm looking at species count data where sampling was carried out over multiple years in repeated sites. So each year was sampled at six different sites for example. The years were categorized into a temperature group with two factors:warm or cold. I'm only interested in exploring community differences between temp. groups and across years. I used the vegan package in calculating diversity metrics(abundance, richness, diversity index) and want to statistically check differences among metrics.
I have been using mvabund package with negative binomial distribution, but I'm wondering if the repeated sites should be added as random effect now, and its actually a mixed model. Would glmmTMB or lme4 be more appropriate in this case? I'm not terribly familiar using mixed models in R so any help is appreciated.
